# Question about weight paint mode

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

So i've recently started to learn blender, but i've encountered a problem with my last model.

When I go into weight paint mode, the whole model is displayed as lines instead of a volume, not allowing me to weight paint the object. Looks like so: [image: weight paint mode image]

Comment: Are you using a Skin modifier? If so, apply it. I don't know why you can't weight paint simple vertices though, but perhaps I'm missing something...

Answer (score 2):

Apply the *Skin* modifier you must have right now, then you'll be able to weight paint.

Comment: Well, we can't use bevel there?

Comment: yes, too bad   :/

Comment: It have bad results?

Comment: I thought you were kidding  ;)  so perhaps elaborate about what you mean

Comment: What if we add a bevel instead

Comment: A Bevel modifier

Comment: Oops, I missed that it was just applying issue, I thought you suggested them to use Skin modifier :p